# swap 2 values in a flex spark list with animation

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

I use Flex4.6

```
<s:List useVirtualLayout="false" dataProvider="{questions}" itemRenderer="myrender" />
```

My goal is to swap 2 items of the list and include a slide animation between them.

ex: item1 goes down and item2 goes up (item1 and item2 are swapped in list).

What I am doing is deleting items item1 and item and recreate them with swpaped indexes.

I am not sure that's the good way and besides I cannot successfully reach the sliding animations between item1 and item2

It was quite easy with Flex3 and itemsChangeEffect

Any clue ?